# Why can't I get a push message in Swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently trying to get a push message. However, you cannot receive a push message. What am I missing?

**AppDelegate**

```swift
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate  {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //create the notificationCenter
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
    
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map{ String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        Log.Info("Registration succeeded!")
        Log.Info("Token: \(token)")
        LocalStorage.set(token, "dacDeviceToken")
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
          if let error = error {
            Log.Error("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
          } else if let result = result {
            Log.Info("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
          }
        }
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        Log.Warning("Registration failed!")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo["gcmMessageIDKey"] {
        Log.Info("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      Log.Info(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo["gcmMessageIDKey"] {
        Log.Info("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      Log.Info(userInfo)

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }


    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
    
    func getNotificationSettings() {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
      }
    }
    

}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        Log.Info("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
        Log.Info(userInfo)
    }

}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        Log.Info("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
}
```

**my Log**

> 2019-09-24 19:31:46.519806+0900 test[586:74065]  -
>
> [I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled.
>
> Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen
>
> name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen
>
> reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean)
>
> in the Info.plist 2019-09-24 19:31:46.756433+0900 test[586:74071]
>
> 6.9.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver
>
> handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging,
>
> add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it
>
> to NO. Follow the instructions at:
>
> to ensure proper integration. 2019-09-24 19:31:46.759687+0900
>
> test[586:74071] 6.9.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics
> v.60102000 started 2019-09-24 19:31:46.760699+0900 test[586:74071]
> 6.9.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled INFO: 2019-09-24 10:31:46 +0000 - 
> AppDelegate.swift messaging(_:didReceiveRegistrationToken:) [Line:196]
>
> Firebase registration token:
> dZ4US-5dJqk:APA91bF0-****************
> INFO: 2019-09-24 10:31:46 +0000 -  AppDelegate.swift
> application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)
> [Line:82]  Registration succeeded! INFO: 2019-09-24 10:31:46 +0000 -
>  AppDelegate.swift
>
> application(*:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)
> [Line:83]  Token:
> 213eba827****************************** INFO:
> 2019-09-24 10:31:46 +0000 -  AppDelegate.swift
> application(*:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)
> [Line:90]  Remote instance ID token:
> dZ4US-5dJqk:APA91bF0-77***********
>
> 2019-09-24 19:31:46.921546+0900 test[586:74071] [MC] System group
> container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
> /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
> 2019-09-24 19:31:46.923537+0900 test[586:74071] [MC] Reading from
> public effective user settings.

**Send Test FCM**
[image: gegg]

[image: fcm]

[image: back]

[image: test]
I don't get anything. My app doesn't receive push messages whether it's in the foreground or in the background.

Please help me a lot.

The token you added in the figure is the device token value. Token values are visible in the log.

### EDIT

I saw the answer and followed it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the answer and followed it, but it doesn't work. However, when you added a new project on the Fire Base, added the iOS app again, and tried, it was successful. I'm not sure what's wrong. Was that a problem with my code?I thought, but when I used the code in the question,also it worked.   I simply created and added a new project for my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can you Put **GoogleService-Info.plist** file in your project?

Try This In My Code 100% Working

```
 import Firebase
    import FirebaseCore
    import FirebaseMessaging
    import UserNotifications
    import UserNotificationsUI

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , MessagingDelegate{

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
            FirebaseApp.configure()

            //Register App For Push Notification
            self.registerAppForPushNotificaition()
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            return true
        }

     func registerAppForPushNotificaition(){
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                let inviteCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "Notification", actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [], options: UNNotificationCategoryOptions.customDismissAction)
                let categories = NSSet(objects: inviteCategory)

                center.delegate = self
                center.setNotificationCategories(categories as! Set<UNNotificationCategory>)
                center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .badge, .alert], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
                    if !(error != nil){
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                        })
                    }
                })
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types:[.sound , .alert , .badge] , categories: nil))
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }


        }
     @available(iOS 10.0, *)
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
        {
    completionHandler(.alert)
    }
     func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                         didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {


            Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
            Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken




            let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token()

            if token != nil {
                fcmID = token!
            }


        }

    func application(application: UIApplication,
                         didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
            Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
            // print(deviceToken)
        }

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

            NSLog("Failed to get Access Token: \(error)")

        }
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
     if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
                return
            }

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        }
     func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {



           print("fcmToken \(fcmToken)")
        }

        func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
            print("remort \(remoteMessage.appData)")
        }
```

Comment: Please look at my edited question. The file has already been added.

Comment: Should I add it to the top of the function?